# How to pass a literal string into drush config-set

Tags: 8, drush

I'm currently attempting to configure the ClamAV module via `drush config-set`. When using the executable mode, the module allows us to specify command-line options to run when the ClamAV executable is triggered.

My attempt to do so is:
`[root@localhost html]# drush config-set clamav.settings mode_executable.executable_parameters '--max-filesize=4095M --max-scansize=4095M --max-embeddedpe=4095M --max-htmlnormalize=4095M --max-htmlnotags=4095M --max-scriptnormalize=4095M --max-ziptypercg=4095M --pcre-max-filesize
=4095M' --y`

Unfortunately, I get the error: 
`Unknown option: --max-filesize.  See`drush help config-set`for available options. To suppress this error, add the option --strict=0.`

Using sh/bash, how do I write this command as to pass in the executable parameters as the setting (a literal string), not as options to drush config-set, as is currently happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use the `--value` option instead of inferring the value by location. See https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/config/config-set/ for the config-set docs.

This won't work, due to a drush bug - see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/225739/64107)

`drush config-set clamav.settings mode_executable.executable_parameters '--max-filesize=4095M'`

but this will:

`drush config-set clamav.settings mode_executable.executable_parameters --value='--max-filesize=4095M'`

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, preface the value with an empty space (inside the quotes).

This appears to be a drush bug. This fails with the unknown option bit:

```
drush config-set system.site name '--max-filesize=blah'
```

However, if I preface the value with a space:

```
drush config-set system.site name ' --max-filesize=blah'
```

this works as expected.

**Edit:** It is also worth noting that `drush config-edit` would bypass this issue altogether, and allow the value to be set via your preferred text editor.

Comment: This was very helpful, and this ultimately solved our problem. Due to my low rep, I can't upvote, but would if I could.